# How can I make an htaccess file on a Mac?

Tags: htaccess

I'm trying to set-up pretty permalinks for my site. WordPress has a warning that my htaccess files is not writable. It provided some code to copy and put in the htaccess file.

I'm on a Mac, my local machine running WordPress 3.1.1.

I coped the code WP provided and pasted it into a new new TextEdit file that I named 1.htaccess . I put the file in the root directory Sites/mysite/. Then I tried to re-name the file and remove the "1", but my Mac gave a warning that files starting with "." are system files and wouldn't let me re-name it.

How can I make an htaccess file on a Mac?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: this isn't really a WordPress question - probably belongs over at superuser.

Comment: @anu would be better at Apple. See my question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11135/how-do-i-create-a-file-with-a-custom-file-extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up terminal. Found in Utilities.

Type:

```
cd /path/to/htaccess/file/
mv 1.htaccess .htaccess
```

For future edits of the htaccess file I'd recommend learning to use vi in the terminal.

```
cd /path/to/htaccess/file/
vi .htaccess
```

Comment: Hi Brady, Thank you so much for the help. It worked! I don't know diddly about Terminal, so I'll have to read up on it. Again, thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

to make hidden files visible in finder, in terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`

then enter

`killall Finder`

and enter again.

change TRUE to FALSE to disable it again.

This will let you see and manipulate files in the Finder that begin with the dot.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked the same question here, personally I thought it was madness that it was so difficult. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11135/how-do-i-create-a-file-with-a-custom-file-extension

The best I answer I found is just to open terminal and use the linux 'touch' command, just `cd` to the correct directory and then execute `touch .htaccess` to create a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the root folder of your WordPress install to writeable by everyone then go in to the Permalink settings and save the .htaccess file will be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Cmd+I (or right click read informations)
Name and extension, here you can choose "keep .htaccess" whereas you can't in the finder.
Keep it simple ;)

Comment: Won't the file become hidden at that point? It has been awhile since I have tried something like that on a Mac.